# Thymeleaf: object in object, could not access value like jsp? Property or field - cannot be found on null

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to access value like:
**user.userSettings.nativeLanguage**
Where :

```
User{
    private UserSettings userSettings
    //gettter & setter
}


UserSettings{
    private string nativeLanguage
    //gettter & setter
}
```

My html:

```
       <table>
            <tr th:each="user:${friends}">
                <td><h3>Name:</h3><h3 th:text="${user.name}"></h3></td>
                <td><h3>Native:</h3><h3 th:text="${user.userSettings.nativeLanguage}"></h3></td>
                <td><h3>Learning: SOME</h3></td>
                <td><a href="/addAsFriend"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active">Add</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

It showed this line:

```
<h3>Native:</h3><h3 th:text="${user.userSettings}"></h3>
```

But not this line not working:

```
<h3>Native:</h3><h3 th:text="${user.userSettings.nativeLanguage}"></h3>
```

And I got error:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'nativeLanguage' cannot be found on null
```

Comment: fix `${user.userSettings.nativeLanguage}` to `${user.userSetting.nativeLanguage}` and define getter method, it seems to work.

Comment: @YukiYoshida, I updated my question. I also see the document. It should be working. But I've tried days to fix, but it is still not working. 
Any idea ?? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved:
I changed from:

```
@RequestMapping("/findfriend")
public String findFreind(Map<String, List<UserAccount>> users){
    users.put("friends", userRepository.findAll());         
    return "find_friend";
}
```

to:

```
@RequestMapping("/findfriend")
public String findFreind(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("friends", userRepository.findAll());        
    return "find_friend";
}
```